# Error while trying to create a war file using NetBeans

Tags: java, ant, netbeans-8

I am trying to create a war file using NetBeans 8 and it gives me the following error. What is the problem?

> filename.xml:45:taskdef class com.jera.anttasks.Query cannot be found using the classloader filename[]

Comment: Please post what you have done so far

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like your ant installation is missing [the Jera Ant Tasks jar](http://www.jera.com/tools/anttasks/)

In Netbeans, click on tools/options/java and then notice the "Ant Home" setting.  Then search for "JeraAntTasks.jar" in this directory. It should be in the [ant home]/lib directory.  If not, then you can download it from [here](http://www.jera.com/tools/anttasks/JeraAntTasks.jar) and copy it to your [ant home]/lib directory. This should fix the problem.

Note that Netbeans does not use the Jera Ant Tasks out of the box, so you are probably trying to compile some customized ant build script.

Hope this helps.